# Caffe2 Flickr Model - What preprocessing is required for Image dataset

Tags: caffe, caffe2

I am trying to run the Flickr style model in caffe2
But I couldn't get the preprocessing steps required for the dataset.
Please  guide me.

Thanks in advance